# Remove assembly binding without rebuild

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have the code which doesn't use the referenced assembly as we decided to use internal mail.

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static bool UseInternalMail
    {
        get
        {        

        return Convert.ToBoolean(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseInternalMail"].ToString();


        }
    }

 public static void SendMail(string message)
 {

  if(UseInternalMail){
   //do via local SMTP
  }
  else{
   //Call a method in 3rd Party assembly, no more using
   3rdPartyDll.Send(message);
  }
 }
}
```

Now we are no more using the 3rdPartyDll. So I have removed this dll from bin folder of my website hosted in IIS.

We are getting the error

**Could not load file or assembly '3rdPartyDll'**

=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: DisplayName = 3rdPartyDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Client/Web/MyWebsite/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Client\Web\MyWebsite\bin

Calling assembly : MyWebsite, Version=2.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Client\Web\MyWebsite\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

Why the code trying to load the assembly before its getting execute.

**Is it possible to remove the assembly with out remove the code and rebuild? Something like remove assembly/redirect in web.config?**

**UPDATE:**

Tried this to use fake assembly with same method signature and dummy implementation but no luck

Placed a dummy fake assembly in bin\Fake folder

```
<runtime>   
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="3rdParty" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="Fake\3rdParty.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>     
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: why don't you just recompile the code with the removed assembly / references, then re-deploy the code to the web server also make sure that there is no reference in the web.config file. test it locally on a Local Instance of your IIS and see if the issue gets resolved after removing the references. also if you are no longer using `3rdPartyDll` then why is it still be called in your code..

Comment: @MethodMan, The source code has many new changes and not tested. So we can't just build and replace the code :( But we asked to remove that assembly

Comment: sounds like you're testing strategy is flawed.. you can fully regression test this prior to pushing a new build to production how else do you expect it to work or find out if it doesn't work..?

Comment: you could just create a new method and create a Static Utils class and everywhere you have `public static void SendMail(string message)` inside that helper class you could add a new method called `SendMailNew(string message)` and do a global search in your code that every where you called `SendMail` do a find and replace with `SendNewMail` since it will have the same method signature

Comment: then show us what the Web.Config key , value looks like for `UseInternalMail`

Comment: That's what Version Control is for. Go back to the source code version the currently used build was made with, make the changes there and create a new build and only change how mails are sent (as per sgmoore's suggestion). If you don't do Version Control, then now is the time to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative when you absolutely cannot change the code is to provide a fake assembly. This assembly needs to have the same name and it needs to export all the types and methods that are used by your project but it doesn't need to implement them.

This only works when the currently used 3rdPartyDll does not have a strong name (i.e. is not signed with a private key that only the original developer has).

Comment: Yes. It doesnt have any public ket token etc. I am trying to do something similar to this by using `<codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="Fake\3rdParty.dll" />` with assemblyBinding

Comment: Just put the fake assembly in the bin folder, so it can be found by the runtime.

Comment: I exactly endup with fake assembly solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Move your code referencing the dll to another method that will never be called.
eg.

```
 public static class Helper
 {
    public static void SendMail(string message)
    {

        if(UseInternalMail)
        {
           //do via local SMTP
        }
        else
        {
          //Call a method in 3rd Party assembly, no more using
          SendUsing3rdPartyDll(message);
        }
    }

    private void SendUsing3rdPartyDll(message)
    {     
        3rdPartyDll.Send(message);
    } 
}
```

The reason you are getting this error is because the runtime compiles each method just prior to it being called and it needs to compile the complete method. By moving the reference to another method, the runtime can compile your SendMail message.

Comment: We couldn't make code change except, web.config change

Comment: unless I am missing something, how does this not differ from the OP's original code.. if that's the case and they don't want to call the 3rdPartyDll regardless if it stays in the compiled code, I would set key in the config file to useInternalMail and set it true so that it will always use the newer code.. that's an even quicker solution as well

Comment: @MethodMan Difference is that that current code requires the dll to be there before it can call into SendMail and hence before it evaluates UseInternalMail. My method the dll is only needed whenever you call into SendUsing3rdPartyDll method.

Comment: Yes it does the trick. Is there any other way to tell the compiler to ignore this via config?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan If you can't change your code, then NineBerry's suggestion is probably your best bet.